# Exercise 6c in section 50 Munkres' Topology textbook.

Tags: general-topology

The problem is as follows:

Given $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^N$ and given compact subspace $C$ of $X$ ($X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable basis); let:
$$U_\epsilon(C) = \{ f: \Delta(f|_C) < \epsilon \}$$
where $\Delta(f):= \sup\{ \operatorname{diam} f^{-1}(\{ z \}) : z\in f(X)\}$. (I assume that $f$ is continuous though it's not written explicitly).

Show that $U_\epsilon(C)$ is open in $\mathcal{C} (X,\mathbb{R}^N)$, the space of continuous functions from $X\to \mathbb{R}^N$ with the topology induced by the sup metric $\rho(f,g) = \sup \{ |f(x)-g(x)| : x\in X \}$.

Now in the text there's a proof of the following for $X$ being compact metrizable space, Munkres proves that $U_\epsilon := \{ f: \Delta(f)<\epsilon\}$ is open in $\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R}^N)$.
(it's on pages: 311-312).
My question: is the proof in the text the same as the proof for exercise 6c, if not then how to change it that it suits it?

Comment: The questions whether some subset of $C(X,\mathbb R^N)$ is open only makes sense if you say what is the topology on $C(X,\mathbb R^N)$. There are [various topologies on function spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Topology_of_function_spaces) which are commonly used. Since you included exact reference to an exercise in Munkres, anybody who has the book at hand can probably find out. However, including the information which topology you are using   would make this post a bit more self-contained.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am using the metric topology with a metric $\rho(f,g) = \sup \{ |f(x)-g(x)| : x\in X \}$.

Comment: I have added information from your comment to the post, since this information will be much better visible there than in a comment.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but for $\Delta(f)$ to make sense, you probably need $X$ to be a metric space. However, I do not see something like that mentioned in the exercise. (I have 2nd edition of Munkres.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak in the exercises we look at $\Delta(f|_C)$, where $C$ is compact subspace of $X$, and $X$ is locally compact, Hausdorff and has a countable basis. I think that by the fact that $C$ is compact Hausdorff and has countable basis means that $C$ is a metric subspace of $X$. I might be mistaken as most of the time I am, I took the course in general topology way back in 2008-2009; so I don't remember a lot from the theorems there.

Comment: P.S I also have the second edition.

Comment: Do you mean *metrizable* rather than *metric*? (I am not sure it makes sense talking about metric subspace, if the original space is not a metric space.)

Comment: Yes, metrizable.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  Being locally compact Hausdorff, $X$ is regular (even Tychonoff), and since it has a countable basis it is then metrizable by Urysohn.

Comment: @purplemonkeydishwasher I understand that. However, there might be many various metrics for the same topology. My problem with the formulation of the question is that it is asking to prove that something dependent on metric, but it does not say which metric. But most probably any metric compatible with the original topology will do.

Comment: I don't understand the metric $\rho.$ If $X=R^N=R$, and $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ then $\rho (f,g)=\infty$

Comment: @user254665 If you have a look at the Munkres' book, in Theorem 50.3 where the author introduced this notation, there is assumption that $X$ is compact. So the supermum will always be finite, whatever the metric is. In the exercise Munkres uses the same notation. However for $f|_C$. Here $C$ is again compact, so the supremum will be finite again. So I think that the way the problem is stated in that book is not entirely correct. (However, it is quite probable that for the remaining parts of the exercise, we do not need metric on $X$, only on $C$.)

Comment: @user254665 For the phrasing of the question here, I am the one responsible for this problem, since I have copied the metric from the OP's comment [into the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1648819/revisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that we have some metric on the subspace $d$ which is compatible with the subspace topology induced from $X$. (The way I understand it, we need to have some metric on $X$ for the expression $\sup\{\operatorname{diam} f^{-1}(z)\}$ to make sense.)

At this point you already know this fact, which was shown as a part of the proof of Theorem 50.5.

> If $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space then the set $$U_\varepsilon=\{f\in C(X,\mathbb R^n); \Delta(f)<\varepsilon\}$$ is open in the sup-metric.

This fact means that that if $f\in U_\varepsilon$, then also some $\delta$-ball around $f$ must be in $U_\varepsilon$. In the other words:

> If $f\in C(X,\mathbb R^n)$ and $\Delta(f)<\varepsilon$, then there exists a real number $\delta>0$ such that $\Delta(g)<\varepsilon$ whenever $g\in C(X,\mathbb R^n)$ fulfills $$(\forall x\in X) d(f(x),g(x))<\delta.$$

Now we simply use this fact for the metric space $(C,d)$ to get a proof of the claim from Exercise 6c.

*Proof.* Let us assume that $f\in U_\varepsilon(C)$, i.e., $\Delta(f|_C)<\varepsilon$. Now there is a $\delta$-ball around $f|_C$ in the space $C(C,R^n)$ such that $\Delta(g)<\varepsilon$ for each $g\in C(C,R^n)$ which belongs to this ball.

Now if we take any $g\in C(X,R^n)$ such that 
$$(\forall x\in X) d(f(x),g(x))<\delta$$
then we also have 
$$(\forall x\in C) d(f(x),g(x))<\delta.$$
This means that the function $g|_C\in C(C,R^n)$ belongs to the $\delta$-ball with the center $f|_C$. And therefore $\Delta(g|_C)<\varepsilon$.

We have just shown that any function $f\in U_\varepsilon(C)$ has a $\delta$-ball around it which is subset of $U_\varepsilon(C)$. This means that $U_\varepsilon(C)$ is an open set. $\square$